# Button randomly switches places when zooming in&out

Tags: html

I am trying to add my own button to a map that I added to my website. But, whenever I zoom in or out the button randomly changes places.

Here is the button's code,

```
    <div class="ol-control" style="z-index:1; left: 20%;" >
        <button id="location-button" title="Get your location"></button>
    </div>

    <div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px;">
        <div class="photon ol-search ol-unselectable ol-control ol-collapsed">
            <input type="search" class="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search...">
               <button type="button" class="ol-revers" title="click on the map"></button>
               <ul class="autocomplete history">
                   <li data-search="0"> 398<i> 9350004 Jérusalem (Israël)</i></li>
                   <li class="copy"><a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="new">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
```

> The CSS file is something that I downloaded so if you need it to
> answer ask and I'll give it.

100% zoom:

[image]

250% zoom:

[image]

500% zoom:

[image]

Comment: Using relative value for `left` like `20%` will move it based on the container size. this is not random. it's hard to tell if this is your problem without the css

Comment: I'll add it now

Comment: Well, the css is two big files which I cant upload here

Comment: Please, if there is any other way without anything to create the button and make it not move like that tell me.

Comment: try to remove the `left: 20%;` in the button container